# Redirect without changing the url in the adressbar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, i want address `chat.example.tk` to display the contents of `example.tk/chat`, but in a way that the address bar still displays `chat.example.tk`

This is the `.htaccess` code i tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chat.example.tk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.tk/chat/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Remove the host name from your rules destination.  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /chat/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i figured it out eventually and now im gonna answer it if someone finds this in the future.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chat\.example\.tk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^((?!chat/).*)$ /chat/$1 [L,NC]
```